# Why is one article used for two nouns and why is it the definite article?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> Clara first bought the five-room house, including **the kitchen and bathroom**, for $3,000 in 1994. ([source](https://www.seattletimes.com/nation-world/10k-donated-to-woman-living-in-poverty-collapsing-home/))

This is the first time ever the article mentions the house's kitchen and bathroom, so shouldn't both be preceded by indefinite articles? Why does the definite article occur here and why is there only one of it?

I thought a sensible sentence should look like:

> Clara first bought the five-room house, including **a kitchen and a bathroom**, for $3,000 in 1994.

Comment: It's **the** kitchen because there's only one that we could possibly be talking about.  "*A* kitchen" means something like "any random kitchen".  "The first time something is mentioned" is not a very precise rule for when to use the definite or indefinite article.

Comment: stangdon, it is a fact that in formal writing, as borne out in this article (which you have to click through to), the article says "a house" ***first*** and at its second mention, it becomes ***the  house***. The definite article ***the*** is therefore inextricably associated with ***a house***. And yes, that is a rule in English writing. And also, works in a lot of speech as well.

Comment: "donations have been pouring in for a  dilapidated home" [random]. Next mention is "she bought the house". In this context, a home and house are synonyms. It is a stylistic writing rule. That said, "**a** is for **identity not known**" and **the** is **for identity known**. So when you mention again a thing that had an indefinite article, you then use the definite article. Here are the rules for definite and  indefinite: http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/articles.html

Comment: I have just made **a comment** [first mention] above this comment. **The comment**[second mention] is intended to clarify why in writing, an indefinite article is used first for something that is not identified and once it is, the definite article is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

It's assumed that the five-room house already has a kitchen and a bathroom, and the reader is reasonably expected to make that assumption. Therefore, "the" is appropriate.

Also, "the kitchen and bathroom" can be written as "the kitchen and the bathroom", but the latter is too wordy and thus omitted for conciseness. In "the kitchen and (the) bathroom", the second "the" is understood.

### Explanation

The rule for "the" isn't necessarily for its noun to have already been mentioned beforehand. Rather, if the reader (listener) can be expected to reasonably answer the question, "which one?", then "the" is appropriate.

In the case of the sentence you posted, the writer says "including the kitchen and bathroom". The reader can ask "which kitchen and bathroom?", and the reader should be reasonably expected to answer it: "the kitchen and bathroom (in the five-room house)".

Comment: I agree that **the** is fine here. However, I think the sentence would have read more naturally as *including* ***its*** *kitchen and bathroom*.

Comment: @JasonBassford, "its" sounds unnatural to me. "I cleaned the house yesterday, including **its** windows" : I think not.

Comment: @JavaLatte Hmm. It still sounds like something I might say. Especially if there is a sense of quantity: *I cleaned the house yesterday—including all of its many windows.*

Comment: Why use "the" to begin with? That's the point.

Answer (score -1):

In the article, we are told she moved into "**a** dilapidated house".

Then, we see "she bought **the** five-room house".

**This follows the a/the rule perfectly.**

I bought **a** house. **The** house is small.

The rule is that if you mention **a** something, the next mention of it will be with a **the**.

"He has **a** very fast car. But **the** car sits in the garage and he never drives it."

The **first mention** of an object, person or idea is often indeterminate and takes **a** and as soon as it becomes specific the second mention you mention it, **it takes the**.

This is one of the simplest rules about a/the.

And if you have a thing that has become specific with definite article the,  the other specific things associated with it are also specific.

I bought a house yesterday. The house and the garage were painted purple.

There is only one house and one garage. **The house didn't have just any garage**, a garage. It was the garage that was associated with the house.

Comment: This doesn't answer either of the points in the question, namely 1) why does kitchen get a **definite** article, despite the fact that the kitchen has never been mentioned before, and 2) why does bathroom **not** get an article, definite or indefinite?

Comment: @JavaLatte  Right, so I edited my answer.

Comment: Better, but why leave in all the "the/a house" stuff? The OP didn't ask about that. And you still don't answer the second point.

Comment: I left it in ***because*** in the actual article, it says "***a house***", first mention and the second mention (which this question is about) then would and does become "***the house***" (in this specific article) so anything that accompanies "the house" also can take a the. The  house with the bathroom and the kitchen cost $3,000. They were not a random kitchen or bathroom. compare: the [specific] house cost $3,000, but that did not include a bathroom and a kitchen [random]. to:  But that did not include the bathroom and kitchen, which cost another $2000, for example.

Comment: To be clear, the use of "the house" is only used because at  the very beginning of the article "a house" is used. You cannot explain "the  house" here without reference to "a house". Once "a house" becomes "the house", the one that costs x, whatever accompanies it follows the "the" specificity rule.